# Отправка сообщения ИДАМ, которые в массиве python

Tags: python, telebot

Здраствуйте, хочу что-бы сообщение отправлялось всем идам, которые в массиве helpers. Вот мой код

```
import telebot
import confgi
bot = telebot.TeleBot(confgi.TOKEN)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def record_id(message):
    helpers = ['964692370','792593084']
    bot.send_message(str(helpers),'Hi brother!')
    needfile = open('needf.py', 'a')
    needfile.write('\n' + (message.chat.id))



bot.polling()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import telebot
import confgi
bot = telebot.TeleBot(confgi.TOKEN)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
    def record_id(message):
        helpers = ['964692370','792593084']
        for _ in helpers:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Hi brother! {_}')


bot.polling()
```

Comment: Здравствуйте. Я бы хотел просить у вас, зачем нужно {_}?

Comment: огромное спасибо

Comment: "_" обычная переменная. Как если бы я написал telegram_id или num.

Comment: Переменная "подчеркивание" традиционно используется для значений, которые потом не планируется использовать. В данном случае лучше использовать обычную переменную с "читаемым" именем.